# Issues with multiple GitHub self-runners on the same server

Tags: github, github-actions

Are there any reasons why this is not a good idea? I ask because I *constantly* experience very, very inconsistent results. For example, while setting up my GH Actions over the last few days, I must have run at least 200 workflows. However, for the first time ever, I am now seeing this error:

```
Run ruby/setup-ruby@v1
  with:
    ruby-version: 3.0.2
    bundler-cache: true
    bundler: default
    working-directory: .
    cache-version: 0
  env:
    BUNDLE_GEMS__CONTRIBSYS__COM: ***
    ImageOS: ubuntu20
Modifying PATH
  Entries added to PATH to use selected Ruby:
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.2/x64/bin
Downloading Ruby
  https://github.com/ruby/ruby-builder/releases/download/toolcache/ruby-3.0.2-ubuntu-20.04.tar.gz
  Took   0.71 seconds
Extracting Ruby
  /usr/bin/tar -xz -C /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.2 -f /home/ubuntu/actions-runner-2/_work/_temp/7d0937cf-69b1-4c73-b1bd-7386fca820a2
  /usr/bin/tar: x64/lib: Cannot utime: No such file or directory
  /usr/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
  Took   0.52 seconds
Error: The process '/usr/bin/tar' failed with exit code 2
```

I have absolutely no clue whatsoever why this would be presenting itself. If I re-run the same workflow, the error goes away. I'm not sure if this is because one runner is conflicting with another while trying to access the `/opt/hostedtoolcache/` directory or something else.

Here's the exact same job re-run without any issues:

[image]

Comment: A runner should be run ideally in a clean environment, so running many of them on the same machine without proper isolation is considered bad practice. In a modern age like this, you are supposed to host multiple runners in their dedicated Docker containers on a single server, and that's how a lot of people do.